# Require SSL on MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, ssl

With web forms I can designate an individual ASPX page to require SSL and IIS will ask the user to pick a certificate from their CAC.  However, in IIS Manager on the server for an MVC site, the individual views are not listed so I cannot require SSL for a particular view.  Is there any way to do this?

My web.config has been changed:

```
 <location path="FileSharing/Welcome" allowOverride="true"></location>
  <location path="FileSharing/Index" allowOverride="true">
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <access sslFlags="Ssl,SslNegotiateCert,SslRequireCert"/>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Error 500.19

Error Code
   0x80070021

Config Error
   This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

Comment: Although individual views are not listed, you could manually create `location` nodes corresponding to MVC paths (for example `location path='home/index'` and there have your `system.webServer/security/access` created manually. Haven't tried that but it should work.

Comment: @WiktorZychla so, to understand what you are saying, I could create a node in IIS manager listing the view or action that I want to require SSL.  Should this be done from the View folder or what?

Comment: The `web.config` is a plain text xml file. It doesn't really matter how you edit it. If you aren't sure how such custom section should look like, create a dummy aspx page, use the IIS manager to create a SSL section for it and then open the config file, find the section and copy-paste it to create another section, but this time change the location to point to your MVC controller/view.

Comment: @WiktorZychla  finally getting back to this.  I placed the location stuff in the web,config file as above.  But I am getting the error I listed as well.  Is there a way around this?  I am running on my local machine in development with IIS Express.